# drawing a disk by analyzing neighbors pixel intensity

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

The picture and code below is a toy example that should reflect an experiment I am running.
I would like to extract a disk corresponding to the boundary in the picture where the pixels intensities are the same or similar (in this example the bluish disk)

Using `HoughCircles` procedure, I can extract the center of the most probable circle of the picture.
From there I would like to probe 360° from the center at the various radius (higher or lower) from the detected center to define the boundaries (max radius and min radius) of the bluish color in the picture below.

How can I do that?
I try to analyze the histogram by applying multiple masks without success.
The green circle is the one detected with `HoughCircles`, the blue and red circle are the +/- 15% radius circle.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("./picture.jpg")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 800,
                                          param1=300,
                                          param2=1,
                                          minRadius=100,
                                          maxRadius=0)

if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    output = image.copy()
    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 2, y - 2), (x + 2, y + 2), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        # create the mask and explore histograms
        # height,width,depth = output.shape
        # mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
        # cv2.circle(mask, (x, y), int(round(r - (r* .15))), 1, thickness=-1)
        # output = cv2.bitwise_and(output, output, mask=mask)

        # hist_full = cv2.calcHist([output],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
        # hist_mask = cv2.calcHist([output],[0],mask,[256],[0,256])
        # plt.hist(image.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()
        # plt.plot(hist_full), 
        # plt.plot(hist_mask)
        # plt.xlim([0,256]) 
        # plt.show()

        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), int(round(r * 1.15)), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), int(round(r - (r* .15))), (0, 0, 255), 2)


    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: My English is poor, so I can't get what's your purpose... Do you want to get the "whole" disk, or what?

Comment: Yes I want to extract the disk, not the gray part but the bluish portion.

Comment: I try to seperate the "disk" like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7kT6.jpg

Comment: Nice, does your code generalize well? Could you share your solution? Thanks

Comment: The main step were tagged on the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks - could you share the code you used to build these steps?

Comment: Ok, I post some core code.

Answer (score 1):

I resized the disk image, because the origin is too large. So you may modify the parameters in the function.

---

**The source**:

[image]

I found in S(HSV), the disk is more clear, so I **did canny in "S"**.

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

**You can reproduce the result using the code.**

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.21 21:03:09 CST
# 2017.11.22 23:21:42 CST
# 2017.11.25 16:32:46 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("disk2.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Canny edge in S(HSV)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)
canny = cv2.Canny(s, 30, 200)

## The inner circle using gray
circles1 = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, method = cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        dp = 2, minDist = 100,
        param1=200, param2=100,
        minRadius=80, maxRadius=200)


## The outer circle using canny
circles2 = cv2.HoughCircles(canny, method = cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        dp = 2, minDist = 100,
        param1=200, param2=100,
        minRadius=200, maxRadius=0)

x1,y1, r1 = circles1[0][0]
x2,y2, r2 = circles2[0][0]

## create the mask
mask = np.zeros_like(canny)
cv2.circle(mask, (x2, y2), r2, 255, -1)
cv2.circle(mask, (x1, y1), r1, 0, -1)

## crop
imask = mask > 0
masked = np.zeros_like(img)
masked[imask] = img[imask]

cv2.imshow("canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("croped", masked)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Simple and sleek code for this problem! Do you have scripts set up already to plot the histograms and the color channels? That's super handy, I think I'll do the same.